# What is the structure of VML mouse event object?

Tags: raphael, vml

I would like to know the structure (properties and methods) of a VML mouse event object.

I'm using Raphael, and I want to know the mouse coordinates when an element is hovered. On Firefox and Chrome, `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` are working, but not in IE8.

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('map', 300, 300));
paper.circle(50, 50, 40).attr({fill: 'black'}).mouseover(function(event){
    alert(event.pageX);
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3hFu/2/).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is not specific to VML : all mouse events have the same structure in IE.
I used `clientX` and `clientY`, with a rectification due to the fact that clientX is the offset relative to the viewport, whereas `pageX` is relative to the page.